# Can't get LESS to compile Imports

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, less, web-essentials

I am using visual studio 2012 with web essentials 2012, latest version.
I am following the direction from this article http://www.cutterscrossing.com/index.cfm/2013/5/20/Skinning-Bootstrap-Tabs.
I have @import directives in the less files and when I save the file a css file is created.  However, nothing is in the css file.
I've checked the path, but the paths appear valid.

My file structure is...

A new empty web site called

```
 bootstrapless project
     css folder
        bootstrap folder
            All bootstrap less files
        core folder
            css folder
               All css files generated from less files in core folder
            core.less
            overrides.less
            variables.less
     img folder
        bootstrap folder
            bootstrap glyphicons-halflings png files
     js folder
        bootstrap folder
            All bootstrap js files
```

In the custom variables.less file I have...

```
 @iconSpritePath:          "../../img/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings.png";
 @iconWhiteSpritePath:     "../../img/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white.png";
```

The variables.css output created upon save is **empty**

In the custom overrides.less file I have...

```
 @import "variables.less";


 [class^="icon-"],
 [class*=" icon-"] {
    background-image: url("@{iconSpritePath}");
 }

 /* White icons with optional class, or on hover/focus/active states of certain elements */
 .icon-white,
 .nav-pills > .active > a > [class^="icon-"],
 .nav-pills > .active > a > [class*=" icon-"],
 .nav-list > .active > a > [class^="icon-"],
 .nav-list > .active > a > [class*=" icon-"],
 .navbar-inverse .nav > .active > a > [class^="icon-"],
 .navbar-inverse .nav > .active > a > [class*=" icon-"],
 .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover > [class^="icon-"],
 .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus > [class^="icon-"],
 .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover > [class*=" icon-"],
 .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus > [class*=" icon-"],
 .dropdown-menu > .active > a > [class^="icon-"],
 .dropdown-menu > .active > a > [class*=" icon-"],
 .dropdown-submenu:hover > a > [class^="icon-"],
 .dropdown-submenu:focus > a > [class^="icon-"],
 .dropdown-submenu:hover > a > [class*=" icon-"],
 .dropdown-submenu:focus > a > [class*=" icon-"] {
   background-image: url("@{iconWhiteSpritePath}");
  }
```

On save, web essentials creates an overrides.css with the following...

```
 [class^="icon-"],
 [class*=" icon-"] {
   background-image: url("../../img/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings.png");
 }
 /* White icons with optional class, or on hover/focus/active states of certain elements */
 .icon-white,
 .nav-pills > .active > a > [class^="icon-"],
 .nav-pills > .active > a > [class*=" icon-"],
 .nav-list > .active > a > [class^="icon-"],
 .nav-list > .active > a > [class*=" icon-"],
 .navbar-inverse .nav > .active > a > [class^="icon-"],
 .navbar-inverse .nav > .active > a > [class*=" icon-"],
 .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover > [class^="icon-"],
 .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus > [class^="icon-"],
 .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover > [class*=" icon-"],
 .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus > [class*=" icon-"],
 .dropdown-menu > .active > a > [class^="icon-"],
 .dropdown-menu > .active > a > [class*=" icon-"],
 .dropdown-submenu:hover > a > [class^="icon-"],
 .dropdown-submenu:focus > a > [class^="icon-"],
 .dropdown-submenu:hover > a > [class*=" icon-"],
 .dropdown-submenu:focus > a > [class*=" icon-"] {
   background-image: url("../../img/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");
 }
```

The last custom less file in the core folder is the core.less file.
This file only has the following imports...

```
 @import "../bootstrap/bootstrap.less";
 @import "overrides.less";
```

When saved an empty css file is created.  Again, empty.

Is there something I'm missing.  I've been over the instructions a few times and everything seems right.

Thanks

Comment: what command do you use to compile?

Answer (score 0):

You should not only save your Less file, but compile them leveraging a Less compiler.

See http://vswebessentials.com/features/less how to compile your Less files with Web essentials.

You can set all the compiler settings from Tools -> Options. They include:

1. Compile on save
2. Compile on build
3. Enable minification